# The path does not belong to a directory in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I have a problem, every time I import a project my professor sent me, I encounter these problems:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E3n4.png
After that, I press File->Project Structure, and this appears:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0xYH.png

After I press ok, it will work, but I wondered how I can avoid that. Is this normal? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the second image, the path it is showing for the SDK that is not present is your Professors system location path whereas the second path is your SDK location.
It is obvious that your Professors Files path will be different than yours File Path as you two are accessing this projects from two different systems.
This is total normal! And you don't need to worry about it.

What is does is its trying to find the SDK location from the path that was added into the properties file when the project was build although this path is different from yours but it's searching the properties into the first path so when you do OK, you give the studio permission to refer the SDK location from your SDK location path.